# Tensorflow-keras : CNN predictions are very close to 1 or 0

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I trained a CNN on 96x96 bacterias images. I have 3 classes : "bacterias", "flocs" and "nothing".

Then, to detect bacterias on a 1920x1080 image, I scan the image with 96x96 windows and I run my CNN for all scanned windows.

But my predictions are always [0,1,0] like. And I never have eg. [0.1, 0.8, 0.1]

Here is my model :

```
batch_size = 32
nb_epochs = 10
taille_image = (96,96)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), input_shape=(96, 96, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))




model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


def Entrainer():

        train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
                rescale=1./255,
                horizontal_flip=True,
                vertical_flip=True,
                validation_split=0.2)
        

        train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                "Images_traitees/Vignettes_squared",
                target_size = taille_image,
                batch_size=batch_size,
                class_mode="categorical",
                shuffle=True,
                save_to_dir="augmented_data",
                save_prefix="augmented_",
                save_format="jpeg",
                subset="training"
        )
        validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                "Images_traitees/Vignettes_squared",
                target_size = taille_image,
                batch_size=batch_size,
                class_mode="categorical",
                subset="validation"
        )

        tbCallback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./Graph', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, write_images=True)
        history = model.fit_generator(
                train_generator,
                steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples // batch_size,
                validation_data = validation_generator,
                validation_steps = validation_generator.samples // batch_size,
                epochs=nb_epochs,
                callbacks = [tbCallback]
        )

        plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
        plt.title('model accuracy')
        plt.ylabel('accuracy')
        plt.xlabel('epoch')
        plt.show()

        plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
        plt.title('model loss')
        plt.ylabel('loss')
        plt.xlabel('epoch')
        plt.show()

        model.save("my_model.h5")


if __name__ == "__main__":
        model.summary()
        Entrainer()
```

[tensorboard results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nw1WU.png)

And this is the code to call my model and color the the detected class.

```
model = load_model("my_model.h5")

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


def Predire(img, vignettes, pos):
    image = Image.open(img)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image, mode='RGBA')

    for vignette in vignettes:
        x = img_to_array(vignette)
        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
        y = model.predict(x)

        if y[0][1] > max (y[0][0],y[0][2]):
            draw.rectangle(pos[nb], outline='red', fill=(255,0,0,125))
            proto +=1
        if y[0][0] > max (y[0][1],y[0][2]):
            draw.rectangle(pos[nb], outline='blue', fill=(0,0,255,125))
            floc +=1
        if y[0][2] > max(y[0][1],y[0][0]):
            draw.rectangle(pos[nb], outline='black')
                    
        print (y)
       

 
    return image
```

When I print y, it returns :

```
[[0. 0. 1.]]
[[0. 0. 1.]]
[[0. 0. 1.]]
[[0. 0. 1.]]
[[1. 0. 0.]]
[[1. 0. 0.]]
[[1. 0. 0.]]
[[1. 0. 0.]]
[[1. 0. 0.]]
[[1. 0. 0.]]
[[1. 0. 0.]]
[[1.0000000e+00 1.7819082e-33 0.0000000e+00]]
[[1. 0. 0.]]
...
```

Each line represents the CNN prediction of a 96x96 sliding windows of the entire image.

I thought it was overfitting, but i tried with only 735 trainable parameters and i have still the same pb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be the case that your model has heavily overfitted the data. Check your models accuracy on your training vs your test set and see if they are reasonable.

**Update**: Turns out preprocessing of the image data was the problem. Always make sure you apply the same preprocessing to both training, validation and test set.

Comment: Yes, that what i thought, but i tried with very few parameters and i have still the same pb

Comment: Sometimes it only takes a "few" parameters for the model to still overfit, so this is not neccessarily a good indicator. Whats your training and test accuracy?

Comment: with 2900 trainable param (fewer than my actual model) : acc :0.94, val_acc : 0.87

Comment: Is it possible that once you switch from your 96x96 images to the 1920x1080 the preprocessing of the image changes i.e. do you rescale with 1./255 as well? I did experienced similar results with models where it turned that those results where due to the fact that the input to the models was different than what I originally trained them on (preprocessing wise).

Comment: Thank you, it solved my pb, i have still strange predictions... I use squared image and then i use the rescale = 1./255 param of the keras image_data_generator. Do you think it is better to add blank padding to fill all my images to the size of 96x96 or there is no problem with rescale ?

Comment: Rescaling should not be affected by padding. However padding might change your results - you should give it a try and see if there is any improvement. Glad I could help! I updated my answer, if it solved your problem feel free to accept it in order to close this :)